# Arredondamento de Valores SQL no comando PRINT

Tags: stored-procedures

boa tarde.

Um exercício da internet pede para calcular quanto tempo determinado investimento consegue pagar uma divida, ambos crescendo a uma taxa de juros por mês.

Observe a procedure criada

```
declare @divida real = 10000
declare @aplicacao real = 1500
declare @taxa_div real = 0.025
declare @taxa_apli real = 0.04
declare @meses int = 1

while (@divida > @aplicacao) begin
    set @divida = (@divida * @taxa_div) + @divida
    set @aplicacao = (@aplicacao * @taxa_apli) + @aplicacao
    set @meses = @meses + 1

end
print @meses
select @divida
select @aplicacao
print @divida
print @aplicacao
print @aplicacao - @divida
```

No final estou exibindo os valores quando observei os seguintes pontos :

- No final quando eu peço pra exibir os valores com o PRINT não é exibido com casas decimais já, utilizando o SELECT as casas decimais são exibidas.
- Quando eu peço pra efetuar a subtração dos valores, o resultado é exibido com casas decimais.

Alguem tem ideia do pq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se quiser que o `print` mostre as casas decimais, deve definir como `decimal` algumas variáveis, ficaria assim:

```
declare @divida decimal(12,4) = 10000
declare @aplicacao decimal(12,4) = 1500
declare @taxa_div real = 0.025
declare @taxa_apli real = 0.04
declare @meses int = 1

while (@divida > @aplicacao) begin
    set @divida = (@divida * @taxa_div) + @divida
    set @aplicacao = (@aplicacao * @taxa_apli) + @aplicacao
    set @meses = @meses + 1

end
print @meses
select @divida
select @aplicacao
print @divida
print @aplicacao
print @aplicacao - @divida
```

> 132
>
> ---
>
> 253995.5781
>
> (1 row(s) affected)
>
> ---
>
> 255539.8906
>
> (1 row(s) affected)
>
> 253995.5781
>   255539.8906
>   1544.3125
>
> Minha opinão: É que o comando `print` não consegue distinguir casas
>   decimais quando uma variável é do tipo real ou é limitada para este
>   tipo de variável.

Comment: Só um detalhe, se você pedir para exibir os valores de  **divida** e    **aplicacao**  dentro do        **WHILE** alguns serão exibidos com casas decimais e  outros não. Alguma ideia?

Comment: Fiz o teste aqui e todos estão saíram com casas decimais.

Comment: deixa as variáveis como real ou float

Comment: Vai depender do uso, para valores monetários penso que o melhor seja o `decimal`.

Comment: Concordo com você. Só queria entender o motivo desse comportamento.